# Cast ActionScript Object to Model

Tags: model-view-controller, object, actionscript, casting

Is there any "automatic way" to casts an "Object" to a personalized Model Data Type in ActionScript 3?

Example:

```
package Example{
   public class ExampleModel{
       private _id:int;
       private _randomAttribute:String;

       public function ExampleModel(){
           _id = 0;
           _randomAttribute = "";
       }

       public function get id():int{
           return _id;
       }

       public function set id(value:int):void{
           _id = value;
       }

       public function get randomAttribute():String{
           return _randomAttribute;
       }

       public function set randomAttribute(value:String):void{
           _randomAttribute = value;
       }
   }
}
```

Then, in some part of my code, lets assume that I have something like this:

```
var _obj:Object = new Object();
_obj.id = 1;
obj.randomAttribute = "Hello World";
```

What I want would be something like:

```
var _exampleModel:ExampleModel = obj as ExampleModel;
```

But when I do this, the result on _exampleModel is null.
Any ideas?
Thanks.

EDIT:

According to *Manish*'s answer, all I changed was the type of p var, which allows me to go through every kind of attribute:

```
public function fromObject(obj:Object):void{
    //p:* includes every type of attributes.
    for (var p:* in obj)
        if (this.hasOwnProperty(p))
            // Set private var directly.
            this["_" + p] = obj[p];
}
```

Thanks *Manish* and *rcdmk*.
Manish's answer was enough for me and according to *rcdmk*'s comment, the p:String isn't about the Type of data that the loop will go through, it is actually the name of the property, which makes sense because every **name** is a **String**.

Comment: Can you tell us more about why you're trying to achieve this? This goes against the grain of ActionScript's design, and there's probably a better way to achieve your goals.

Comment: When a user double clicks a record on a dataGrid, I automatically open a different state that contains the form for that entity and fill all the fields with his register (dataGridId.selectedItem). But this is an Object and when I'm going to send this for PHP, I "manually" cast the whole form to a Personalized Model. If I can bound the form with the Model, I no longer need to go through all the fields and set the Model attribute one by one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to automatically "cast" it is the following:

```
var model:Model = new Model();
var obj:Object = { id: "98123", name: "John Doe" };

for (var p:String in obj) {
    if (model.hasOwnProperty(p))
        model[p] = obj[p];
}
```

(Note: `Model.id` and `Model.name` are both type `String` in my example.)

A more proper way to do it, of course, is to pass the plain object to the `Model` object and let the `Model` object absorb it.

```
var model:Model = new Model(obj);
```

Or:

```
var model:Model = new Model();
model.fromObject(obj);
```

Where in the `Model` code you have:

```
public function Model(obj:Object = null)
{
    if (obj != null)
        fromObject(obj);
}

public function fromObject(obj:Object):void
{
    for (var p:String in obj)
        if (this.hasOwnProperty(p))
            // Set private var directly.
            this["_" + p] = obj[p];
}
```

This code can be in your abstract base `Model` class, and all your specific `Model` subclasses (e.g. `ProductModel`, `CustomerModel`, etc.) can use it automatically.

e.g.

```
public class ProductModel extends Model
{
    public function ProductModel(obj:Object = null)
    {
        super(obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: I gotta admit that this is easier than mapping manually every Model, but one question: You're mapping only Strings? What about other types?

Comment: This can map any value. The string in the `for` is for the `property name` of each property the object have and use it as a key on the square braquets notation to access the variables of the model.

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu No, it maps any type, not just `String`.